# Eloquent accessors and property naming

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm defining my class as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'first_name'
    ];

    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value = null)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

Then I populate my DB with entry for that model:

```
\App\Models\Foo::create(['first_name' => 'foo']);
```

Then I'm calling accessor as follows:

```
\App\Models\Foo::first()->first_name;
=> "Foo"
```

which is expected

and

```
\App\Models\Foo::first()->firstName;
=> ""
```

which is unexpected (but understandable as even though `getFirstNameAttribute` method is being called, DB property `firstName` is being accessed and that doesn't exist)

I'd like to ensure that in both cases correct property (`first_name`) is being accessed.

Does this mean that `($value = null)` is unreliable and one should always rely on `$this->attributes['first_name']`?

As such, this code becomes:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value = null)
{
    return ucfirst($this->attributes['first_name']);
}
```

Though I'd probably expect

```
>>> \App\Models\Foo::first()->first_____na______me;
=> "Foo"
```

to not do this.

Comment: By convention `getFirstNameAttribute` corresponds to `first_name` not `firstName`

Comment: I think the main issue is that you're defining an accessor that is the same as your column name. `getFirstNameAttribute()` allows access to `$model->first_name`, which is already a column. If you did `getModifiedFirstNameAttribute()`, then you'd be able to call either `$model->modified_first_name` or `$model->modifiedFirstName`

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `->first__na__me` work with `->attributes` or with `$value` ?

Comment: @apokryfos it works with `attributes`, it doesn't work with `$value` due to same principle (`first_____na______me` doesn't exist within the DB). My main problem I guess here is that if `getFirstNameAttribute` method is called for `firstName` then proper property should be passed through to $value. And if I'm accessing `first_____na______me` then `getFirstNameAttribute` shouldn't be called

Comment: @TimLewis I think it's totally fine - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor makes references to accessing DB column this way.

Comment: Hmm, interesting; I recall having issues with this in the past, but maybe that's not a thing anymore  Either way, for clarity, I tend to avoid running into ambiguous cases like that

Comment: But there's no `fistName` field in your database is there? When you call `->first_name` it will look for an accessor and call it with the underlying database value (which exists). If you call `firstName` it will call the same accessor but with no underlying database value (since it does not exist).

Comment: @apokryfos that's correct - my expectation though is that in both cases `first_name` property should be passed (as `first_name` property is linked to `getFirstNameAttribute` accessor). The same way `first_____na______me` call shouldn't be linked to that accessor, because it's not snake case nor it does even translate to that name (would be `firstNaMe` if PHP were to provide case differences for methods). I'm not denying that my understanding might be flawed, hence this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to access a model attribute then Laravel will (a) try to retrieve the given attribute and (b) look for an accessor which matches the attribute you attempted to access.

However the convention is that database fields are named using [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)  and PHP functions are named using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (with one humped camels). The rule for naming accessors is `get{AttributeName}Attribute` which means that to find whether there's an accessor for `first_name` then Laravel will convert the `first_name` to StudlyCase (or two humped CamelCase or PascalCase) and look for a function called `getFirstNameAttribute` and then call it using the underlying database value as a parameter. It will always do this regardless of what the attribute requests was named. It does not actually have to be snake_case

However the problems are:

1. PHP function names are not case sensitive. This means that calling `getFirstNameAttribute` as `getFirstNaMeAttribute` will work just fine and call the same method
2. an accessor for `FirstName` will have the same name as an accessor for `first_name`

Therefore your `->first_na__me` call will look for an accessor `getFirstNaMeAttribute` and `->firstName` will do the same, however only `first_name` will have an actual underlying database value to pass in the `$value` parameter.

It's easy to determine what accessor `first_name` corresponds to but it's really hard to determine what database value `getFirstNameAttribute` corresponds to because php function names are not case sensitive so you can go one way but not the other. Therefore it's just easier to get the literal database field and then call the accessor rather than associate an accessor with a database field

Comment: I'd disagree - for `__FUNCTION__` strip get and Attribute (per Laravel convention for accessors), turn first into lowercase, snake case the result - you end up with correct property (although tbf I don't know if convention of `getFooBarAttribute` is a convention for Laravel - I always see it as such, never `getFoobarAttribute` to provide access for `foo_bar` property; such accessor would provide access for `foobar`)

Comment: I appreciate your response - would you mind sharing your thoughts on accessing `$value` though? Why provide it as a parameter when actual value changes depending on the way property was accessed?

Comment: Look at it this way. It's the only way to know whether you accessed the accessor via `first_name` rather than `firstName` in case you want to have both work in your model. Not sure if this was the intention though. It could be a coincidence. Sometimes things are the way they are because of quirks in the way they were coded rather than conscious decisions

Comment: Thank you - while it's not a satisfactory answer, it is an answer